# Powershell Get-Package not filtering properly

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.0

I am having this issue with filtering of application with Get-Package cmdlet

when  I use the below code,

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "server01" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { Get-Package -Name  "Google Chrome"}
```

it is properly filtering out `Chrome` from the remote machine.(see below)

[image]

if I assign Chrome to a variable, like below

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$app = "Google Chrome"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "server01" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { Get-Package -Name  $app}
```

Its showing all the applications installed in the remote machine.

[image]

What seems to be the issue here ? Is it not the proper way to assign variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Had to use $Using in front of variable

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$app = "Google Chrome"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "server01" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { Get-Package -Name  $Using:app}
```

This worked.